# Schema.org RDFa: marking up <img> as ImageObject?

Tags: schema.org, rdfa

I'm using Schema.org and RDFa to mark up an HTML page. I have an image as follows:

```
<div class="image_container">
    <a href="big_whatever.jpg">
        <img src="whatever.jpg" alt="A picture of Whatever" title="Whatever">
    </a>
</div>
```

What is the correct way to mark this up, so that:
1. big_whatever.jpg (the link href) becomes the contentUrl
2. The alt property becomes the description
3. The title property becomes the name
4. Ideally, I would also like the alt property to be the caption, as well.

Now, this is easy enough with JSON-LD, but I prefer to use RDFa for this particular case. This is what I've got so far:

```
<div class="image_container" vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="ImageObject">
    <a href="big_whatever.jpg">
        <img src="whatever.jpg" alt="A picture of Whatever" title="Whatever">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use the values of `alt` or `title` attributes in RDFa.

You could duplicate them with "hidden" `meta` elements:

```html
<div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="ImageObject">
  <a property="contentUrl" href="big_whatever.jpg">
    <img src="whatever.jpg" alt="A picture of Whatever" title="Whatever" />
    </a>
  <meta property="description caption" content="A picture of Whatever" />
  <meta property="name" content="Whatever" />
</div>
```

If you don’t need a `property` on the `img` element (e.g., for [`thumbnailUrl`](http://schema.org/thumbnailUrl)), you could use `property`+`content` to save one `meta` element:

```html
<div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="ImageObject">
  <a property="contentUrl" href="big_whatever.jpg">
    <img src="whatever.jpg" alt="A picture of Whatever" title="Whatever" property="name" content="Whatever" />
    </a>
  <meta property="description caption" content="A picture of Whatever" />
</div>
```

Thanks to the `content` attribute, RDFa won’t use the `src` value. But I think it’s more clear to go with the first snippet.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I opted not to use the "meta" element solution, as search engines discourage the placing of important content in hidden elements. I ultimately opted to use JSON-LD, as this gives better control over the metadata.

Comment: @Bintz: Okay, but it’s really not needed to go this way. As *everything* is hidden with JSON-LD, and search engines are capable to handle this, there should be no problem with using intended (!) features of RDFa.  Several official examples (from Schema.org as well as Google etc.) use Schema.org with hidden `meta`/`link` elements. The idea is not to use this to "spam", but there are many valid cases where you should (and even cases where you have to) use `meta`/`link` in RDFa. As the content in your case actually exists in the markup, using hidden elements is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, understood, and thank you for making these points in this thread. The decisive factors in choosing JSON-LD is that actually I prefer it. I find it to be cleaner, more logical and easier to debug. I thought that RDFa would be easier to use in the particular situation I was working on, but ultimately the amount of additional work turned out to be equivalent, so I choose the JSON-LD that I had worked with previously.